# String.valueOf vs getString

Tags: android

What are the differences between getString and String.valueOf?

In my case, I have declared "bgDefault" in strings.xml as:
`<string name="bgDefault">#0C090A</string>`

I can print out the value with `Log.d("xyz", R.color.bgDefault);` This also works: `getString(R.color.bgDefault)`, but why does `String.valueOf(R.color.bgDefault)` not also work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of the compilation process is generating the `R.java` file. This contains a bunch of `static final int`s that are used to look up resource values. They are organized to reflect what type of resource they will find, but as far as Java is concerned, they are just integers.

The `getString(int)` method in `Context` and its subclasses (like `Activity`) are meant specifically to look up a string resource that was included in your app, and it takes a string resource id as a parameter to know which resource to find. Again, in Java this parameter appears to be just a normal integer.

`String.valueOf(int)` is entirely different. It is a Java library function that takes an integer and produces a String representation of that integer, e.g. `String.valueOf(5)` returns `"5"`. It is not useful for getting Android string resources.

As an aside, you don't need to use string resources to define colors like that. You can define a color resource instead.

```
<resources>
    <color name="bgDefault">#0C090A</color>
</resources>
```

To get the proper color int in Java, you need to do this:

```
int bgColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.bgDefault);
```

`getResources()` is a method defined by Context and its subclasses (like Activity), so you can use it inside of your Activity.